# Apagar parte de texto com Python

Tags: python

Como faço para apagar parte de um texto em Python ?

Tenho a seguinte string

```
 """ 
    texto textinho 
    outro texto

    <div dir 'ltr'><div><div> bla bla ....

 """
```

quero apagar toda parte HTML.

Estou usando Python2.7

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar uma expressão regular para apagar tudo o que estiver entre os os marcadores "<" e ">", de uma vez.

```
>>> string = """ 
...     texto textinho 
...     outro texto
... 
...     <div dir 'ltr'><div><div> bla bla ....
... 
...  """
>>> 
>>> import re
>>> print re.sub(r"<.+?>", "", string)

    texto textinho 
    outro texto

     bla bla ....
```

Repare em particular na subsituição por `""` - string vazia  -e no uso do `?` na expressão regular, que faz com que ela pare de achar no primeiro sinal de fechar tag (`>`) - senão a expressão pegaria todo o texto desde a abertura da primeira tag, até fechar a última.

Answer (score 0):

Eu resolvi com a seguinte REGEX

```
import re  
m = re.findall("[<][\w|\W]*[>]*", str(corpo), re.IGNORECASE)

for i in m:
    corpo = corpo.replace(i, "")
```

Que apaga TUDO que tiver:

```
    <QUALQUER_COISA> ISSO TAMBÉM <OPA ISSO TAMBÉM>
```

Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score -1):

eu consegui assim

```
import re

string = """ 
    texto textinho 
    outro texto

    <div dir 'ltr'><div><div> bla bla ....

 """

r = re.search("[<].*[>]",string)

# retorna "<div dir 'ltr'><div><div>"
r.group(0)

result = string.replace(r.group(0),"")

#result vai conter ' \n    texto textinho \n    outro texto\n\n     bla bla ....\n\n '
```

Comment: Obrigado William, vou testar e posto os resultados.

Comment: Esse jeito não é bom: sem o uso de "?" no `.*` - (veja minha resposta) - a expressão retorna o espaçõ comprometido entre todas as tags da string da pirmeira até a última. Se você arrumar isso, do jeito que vcê está fazendo, apagaria apenas a primeira tag - todas as outras ficariam lá. Se você iteragir sobre todos os grupos retorandos, usando string.replace para cada grupo, funcionaria, mas seria muito mais lento - uma vez que o puthont eria que fazer uma nvoa busca e substituição, e criar uma nova versão da string, para cada tag no HTML.